# C++ run 2 programs at the same time -SMS getaway-

Tags: c++, qt

I made a C++ program on Qt that does following:

```
//CONNECT TO SERIAL 1
//CONNECT TO DATABASE
while(true)
{
query.exec("SELECT id, phone, message FROM USERS WHERE codesend=0 LIMIT 0,1");
 if (query.next())
 {
 int id = query.value(0).toInt();

 // Update database: SET "SEND" to 1
 query.prepare("UPDATE USERS SET codesend=1 WHERE ID= :nid");
 query.bindValue(":nid", id);
 query.exec();

 //SEND SMS, I DONT DISPLAY IT THATS NOT THE PROBLEM
 }
}
```

This is working great!
The problem is:
I have a lot of serial ports able to send sms, in the code above I only use one.
For the moment I use 2 of them. I copy and paste this code and run 2 programs. The only difference is that they connect to another serial port. -They connect to the same database-

The problem when connecting to 3 serial ports, with 3 programs, is that sometimes it send 2 times the sms because time between `SELECT` and `UPDATE` is too long.

EX.:
Program 1 `select`, program 2 `select`, program 1 `update`... too late program 2 has already selected and will also send...

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `LOCK` on the table in the database. This way only one app can query the db at a time, the other apps will block until they are allowed to read.

```
mysql> LOCK TABLES USERS WRITE
```

after having done your work (after the update) unlock using:

```
mysql> UNLOCK TABLES
```

Answer (score 2):

Quick fix, have only one program call the data base, then communicate the data to the others.

But this is difficult due to interprocess communication difficulties and synchronization, instead you can use threads in one program.

Concept program

```
std::mutex mtx;

Data GetSelect() {
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck (mtx); // insure mutual exclusive with RAII

  query.exec("SELECT id, phone, message FROM USERS WHERE codesend=0 LIMIT 0,1");
  if (query.next()) {
    int id = query.value(0).toInt();

    // Update database: SET "SEND" to 1
    query.prepare("UPDATE USERS SET codesend=1 WHERE ID= :nid");
    query.bindValue(":nid", id);
    query.exec();

    ... put query in data

    return data;
  }
  return EndToken;
}

// function called by thread
void SendSMS(int SerialPort) {
  //CONNECT TO SERIAL SerialPort
  auto data = GetSelect();        
  while(data != EndToken) {
    //SEND SMS, I DONT DISPLAY IT THATS NOT THE PROBLEM
    data = GetSelect();
  }
}

int main() {
  //CONNECT TO DATABASE

  // make and start threads with different serial ports.

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

A more ambitious goal could be to use all modems for all querys, the way to do this is to find a thread safe queue, put the individual results/records into the list and let some worker threads consume from the list.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think I'll need to use threads, but I'm novice... so before having a developper I'll use the easy of @Sebastian Lange

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you execute AT commands to send the sms, possibly turning on/off the modems attached to the serial ports. In such a scenario, why not tackle the problem from another POV and use a multithreading approach as proposed also by Surt?

You can execute just **one** program managing all the different serial ports. Threads can be spawned for a single sending or (better in my view) coded to work as "sms sending services" for the main thread. In either case, it is the main thread which executes both the select and the update commands (asap a thread has sent its assigned sms).

Take a look at [QT Concurrent](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtconcurrent-index.html), [QThread](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qthread.html) and [QRunnable](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qrunnable.html) or simply define your serial port/modem handler as a class and then [move it to a thread](http://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/). Signal-slots can be used to cummunicate the sms to be sent and get back the outcome of the sending.

Hope this helps!